PnL of a "buying the basis" spread trade - US treasury
Let's say you buy a bond (bill to keep it simple), and short a strip Fed fund futures to hedgr and pick up a spread of let's say FFE+10bps.
If this spread were to compress 5 bps, to FFE+5bps, is that MTM PnL of the trade simply the dv01 of the bond * 5 bps?

Yes that is correct

Thanks, had a follow up on this. Does the maturity of the bond with spread compression matter? For example if it is a 6m bill vs a 1yr bill? Is it still just dv01 * spread?

The formula works for any maturity
